# Using GPU to rasterize image with 128 color channels

Tags: gpu, rasterizing

I need to rasterize a [multispectral image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multispectral_image), where each pixel contains the intensity (8 bits) at 128 different wavelengths, for a total of 1024 bits/pixel.

Currently I am using OpenGL, and rasterizing in 43 passes, each producing an image with 3 of the 128 channels, but this is too slow.

Is it possible to do it in a single pass by somehow telling the GPU to rasterize a 128 color component image (not necessarily using OpenGL)?

Comment: I think we need some more details about what you want your end product to be. do you want to end up with 43 images? Or does your end result combine them into one?

Comment: Yes, the end result should be a single image. Right now I am only splitting it up into 43 passes since I can only rasterize 3 channels at a time, and recombining them all in a single image.